# Unable to run MATLAB

Tags: 12.10, java, matlab

I barely managed to get MATLAB installed but I think it's installed correctly. However, when I `cd` to the `bin` directory and run `./matlab`, the MATLAB logo comes up but then it instantly closes again and I get the error message:

```
License checkout failed. License Manager Error -2 

Make sure that the formatting of the license file is correct. When editing the license file use a basic text editor.
Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2012b/2

Diagnostic Information: Feature: MATLAB 

License path: /home/x/.matlab/R2012b_licenses:/home/x/MATLAB1/licenses/license.dat:/home/x/MATLAB1/licenses/network.lic 

Licensing error: -2,413. System Error: 2 ~/MATLAB1/bin$ ./matlab Fatal Error on startup: 

Cannot locate com/mathworks/jmi/OpaqueJavaInterface class
```

I've looked at the solution prescribed on the MathWorks website but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do. I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the license look ok when you go to the mentioned path?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you should put the license file into the following folder

> License path: /home/x/.matlab/R2012b_licenses:/home/x/MATLAB1/licenses/license.dat:/home/x/MATLAB1/licenses/network.lic

Comment: Those seem like many folders. Which one should I use?

Comment: you can put it under 

/home/x/.matlab/

or 

/home/x/.matlab/R2012b_licenses

The semi colon is just to separate many paths.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by actually double checking that I had the right license. It turned out I had a different network.lic, and that's why my previous network.lic didn't work. I opened it up, and copied the same one another computer in the building had, and it worked fine.